# How to bundle my website in xampp

Tags: php, angular, xampp

I'm working on a project in angular 4 as my (front-end) and php as my (back-end) which I want to deploy locally. Is it possible for me to bundle my application in xampp(httdocs) folder and rebuild the xampp since xampp is an open source?
**NB** That means by installing xampp the application will install along with the xampp. Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: No, there are better tools to *"package"* your app like using docker containers, or distribute it as a composer project. If your idea comes from needing to move your project around you should be using git for that.

Comment: You could also use the PHP internal webserver. `php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: Thanks, I will go through those suggestion @LawrenceCherone